# Highlight unwanted spaces in Vim, except for those in help buffers

Tags: vim, whitespace

I am using these lines in my `.vimrc` file, to highlight leading whitespace (which includes spaces):

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=darkgreen guibg=darkcyan
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /^\s* \s*\|\s\+$
```

So, this works fine in most cases. Except in help buffers, where it highlights a lot of indentation from the help files. I find this annoying, so I tried this as a workaround:

```
autocmd FileType help highlight clear ExtraWhitespace
```

But unfortunately, as soon as a help buffer is opened, it seems that the highlighting in all my buffers disappears.
Any ideas on how to improve this?

Comment: By the way, how is one supposed to ask a question about help-buffers in here? I understand why SO refuses the 'help' tag or the 'help' word in the title, so is there a recommended way of asking such questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working:

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=darkgreen guibg=darkcyan
autocmd BufEnter * if &ft != 'help' | match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/ | endif
autocmd BufEnter * if &ft == 'help' | match none /\s\+$/ | endif
```

[edit] The above code works for trailing spaces since my Vim couldn't understand your pattern. So just `:%s/ubstitute` the pattern to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the whitespace errors for C/C++ files you can always use:

```
let c_space_errors=1
```

There are other languages that have similar support.

Worst case, if you need it for other types of files, you could always switch your file type to C and fix your errors then.

Comment: Thanks for that. I use Vim to edit many types of files, not only C or C++ ; but I'll try and keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Change the autocommand disabling custom highlighting in help buffers
as follows:

```
:autocmd FileType help match none
```

Comment: OK, I tried just running `match none` in a help window, which works and removes the highlighting just on the help buffer. But the `autocmd` doesn't seem to work. :-(

Comment: Nope, no error message appears. For what it is worth, I also tried to add something like ` | echo "hello" ` afterwards, and `"hello"` gets printed. I do not know what is going on there...